# Im trying to texture paint on my character with a png but another png i use on my eyes are interfering

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting

Whenever I left click to paint ,the sharingian eye texture Appears even though I used a different png image on nodes witch is the background image you see

[image]

Comment: Which material slot is selected?